# SwiftUI Divider widens its parent view too much

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

SwiftUI `Divider` behaves as if it has `frame(maxWidth: .infinity)`. So it widens its parent view.

How can I prevent Divider from widening its parent view in the below code?

```swift
HStack {
    VStack {
        Text("AAA")
        Divider()
        Text("BBB")
    }
    .background(Color.orange)

    Text("BodyBodyBodyBodyBodyBodyBodyBodyBodyBody")
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .background(Color.blue)
}
```

### Expected

[image]

### Actual

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```swift
HStack {
    VStack {
        Text("AAABBCCDD")
        Divider()
        Text("BBB")
    }
    .fixedSize() //<- Added here
    .background(Color.orange)
    
    Text("BodyBodyBodyBodyBodyBodyBodyBodyBodyBody")
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .background(Color.blue)
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to be a perfect solution.

Comment: You're welcome.